# Count number caught per day from longer intervals

Tags: r

I would like to know how many beetles were caught every day, if the traps have been emptied once per several days.

I have: beetle counts and day of the year (`doy`) when the trap was emptied. I think to get the value per day, I need to:

- fill in missing days (`doy`)
- calculate numbers of days before emptying the trap => 'period' (inlude the day of emptying the trap)
- divide the count of beetles per days without emptying the trap.

But, not sure how to do it?

Here is where I am at:

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(count = c(10,15,23),
                doy = c(6, 11,15))

# expand dataframe to have all days of interests 
doy.df<- data.frame(doy = 5:20)

# expand values
doy.df  %>% 
  full_join(df) %>% 
  arrange(doy) %>%
  mutate(c0 = coalesce(count, 0)) %>% # replace NA by 0; if needed for cumsum
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(c0),
         period = length of period) # get cumulative sums fr control
  mutate(daily = (period)/beetle_count ) # pseudocode for daily counts
```

Desired output:

```
  #    doy count c0 cumsum period daily
  # 1    5    NA  0      0  2        5
  # 2    6    10 10     10  2        5
  # 3    7    NA  0     10  5        1
  # 4    8    NA  0     10  5        1
  # 5    9    NA  0     10  5        1
  # 6   10    NA  0     10  5        1  
  # 7   11    15 15     25  5        1  
  # 8   12    NA  0     25           2
  # 9   13    NA  0     25           2
  # 10  14    NA  0     25           2
  # 11  15    23 23     48           2
  # 12  16    NA  0     48          NA # as we have no further data
  # 13  17    NA  0     48
  # 14  18    NA  0     48
  # 15  19    NA  0     48
  # 16  20    NA  0     48
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you might be making the problem harder than it needs to be.

- use `diff()` to compute days since last emptying (you do need to fill information about when the traps were first set out; I've assumed the first day was 5 here since that's what it seems to be from your example)
- divide

```r
df <- data.frame(count = c(10,15,23),
                doy = c(6, 11,15))
first_day <- 5
df$period <- diff(c(first_day, df$doy))+1
df$daily <- df$count/df$period
```

This is all in base R: you can use tidyverse pipes + `mutate()` or base R (`transform()` or `with()`, with or without pipes) if you want to make the code prettier

```
  count doy period daily
1    10   6      2   5.0
2    15  11      6   2.5
3    23  15      5   4.6
```

- If you do want to fill in all the other days you do need something like this (with tidyverse):

```r
(df 
  |> full_join(data.frame(doy = 5:20))
  |> arrange(doy)
  |> tidyr::replace_na(list(count = 0))
)
```

- not sure what you want to do with `count` after the last trap collection: should that be `NA` rather than 0?
- I'm not sure why you're using (difference in days) +1 rather than (difference in days) as the period, seems inconsistent?

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I have removed `+1` as it was not needed here. You are right, I do not need the values for each day, this gives me the nice avegare, and keeps the table shorter. I prefer the solution with the tidyverse, as I have many traps over several years, so I need to use grouping variable.